# Add elements(nodes) to existing xml file using php

Tags: php

I want to add elements(nodes) to existing xml file. 
Ex:


   
      s
   
   
       

I want to add node author tag after title tag .How can write? can i have to use xpath?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

A little hint: [some search results..](http://www.google.nl/#hl=nl&source=hp&q=php+add+xml+node&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=cb60f85351845f24)

Answer (score 0):

Load your xml from string([doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php)) or a file([doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php)) using SimpleXML.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
```

Then use addChild method of SimpleXML to insert node at particular point http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addChild.php.

**Edited:**
You can loop through nodes using SimpleXML children() method http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php

```
foreach ($xml->children() as $children) {
}
```